# Loading bundle identifiers for KEYNAME failed. Authentication credentials are missing or invalid

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I've bene following the instructions at https://labs.codemagic.io/your-first-flutter-app-to-appstore/#4 but ran into this error, of which I'm finding no information on Google. Does anyone know how I'm supposed to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to double check credentials you provided (as the error message said). If the issue persists can you share more information and screenshots about steps to reproduce the issue?